How do I make the sound from youtube page play on the speaker which has already bluetooth paired?
I have bluetooth paired my speaker, but safari won't play the sound to it. Safari (Chrome too) still uses my macbook to play the sound.
But if I use a headphone, Safari can play the sound to the headphone.
How do I let them play the sound from my speaker.

Safari can only play the sound to the headphone not speaker. Both iTune and VLC have an option to choose audio output device, but browsers do not have this option.

The Chrome help document says I need to "Cast to a device", but unfortunately I didn't see that option on mac (I have tried two macbooks)


Try deleting the Bose connection and pairing it again to see if that fixes it

No, that is not the reason, I feel it is likely browsers do not support that.

Did you try the suggestion Doug made?

Hi I have new finding and now I am really confused whose problem it is. Please see my update.

Hi 6 months later I finally solved it. Check my answer.

With apple tech support's help I finally solve it. It is because I have used other mac to connect to this bluetooth speaker before. So when the second mac connects to the speaker, even though they are bluetooth paired, the sound output setting will be set to Built-in. I have to click Bluetooth manually to make sound come out of the bluetooth speaker.

